# Binary-Classification in Groups

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression, data-modeling

I'm working on what I suppose is a binary classification problem.

Suppose that I have 3 example sentences. For each sentence, I divide it into arbitrary chunks. Now, sentence S might have X(n) chunks for n = 1...4. For the purpose of using supervised learning on my problem, I label one of these chunks as the correct chunk, say X(2) = 1 while the rest is labeled zero, X(1,3,4) = 0.

I would now like to train a classifier on this, with the property, that in case it labels one chunk from sentence S positively, then it cannot label any other chunk from sentence S positively. That is all leftover chunks in S become zero automatically.

I understand that this somehow constitutes dependencies in my data, but I am not sure how to model it correctly/which type of modelling to use.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I keep coming back to this -- it's an interesting extension of the existing milieu.  Exactly what is the output of this model?  Is it the entire sentence plus a chunk index?  An array of chunks plus the index?  Only the "winning" chunk?  So far, it looks like one extra input and one extra output stage on a canonical NN scoring.

Comment: Upon optimisation, the output of the model should preferably be the coefficients that yield the highest classification of the correct sentences in all of the training data, which would hopefully carry over to the test data. That is, if we fed in a test example with chunk(n), n between 1...6, then the model should be most likely to choose the "correct" chunk.

Comment: Got it.  I recommend pushing lejiot's thread of discussion, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it looks like a simple classification, simply your input is of form

```
chunk 1, chunk 2, chunk 3, chunk 4
```

and the output is a one hot-encoding of a label saying which chunk is positive, that's all. So you have normal "multiclass" classification, noting more.

There is no need to go to any complex structured predictors.

Comment: The problem I see is that the same sentence chunk could appear at different indices in the corpus.  The content is important, rather than the index ... I think ...

Comment: how does it matter? If you put all chunks together, and you assume that it is possible to distinguish between them, it is still just a classification. You could also give a full context as additional input, it would not change the fact that it is just a multiclass classification, even if it requires a complex sequence analysis

Comment: Trying to make the post-processing simpler, if possible.

Comment: The content matters indeed. I should note though that I transform each chunk into x features, where each feature is an n-gram probability for n=1...4

Comment: I am a bit confused as to how I can do a multiclassification here? Firstly, the chunks don't belong to any classes, but are arbitrary (with only one of them being the correct one). Secondly, it might be that chunk 1 is the correct one in one instance, whereas chunk 2 is correct in another instance.

Comment: It does not matter. Classifierhas k input slots for chunks and answers which chunk is positive. This is multiclass in such scenario. The function constructed in such manner is well defined, and it does not matter that chunks have different meaning in different settings. Chunks are not your training samples. Ordered list of chunks is a single training sample

Comment: @lejlot makes sense. Would this also work when the number of chunks vary for each training example, such that say label 1-13 exists but sometimes we are only classifying over label 1-5?

Comment: @lejlot I have been trying to make it work through sklearn following this example: [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classification_probability.html). However, I am unsure how to supply the data in the correct format. Each chunk has four features, stored like this [0.21321, 0.91, 0.503, 0.84726]. Each training sentence would then be [[x,x,x,x],[y,y,y,y],...] and I'd have to denote which index in this array corresponds to the right chunk (as a target). However, sklearn training only takes a 2d array for fitting, not a 3d. How would I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would add some detail to @lejlot's answer.

In my case, each chunk consists of 4 features (f_num). If n be the number of training examples, then each training example X(n) has an arbitrary number of chunks, X(c_num). In order to do the proper multiclass classification on them, I manipulate the data, such that each training example becomes a list of k entries, where k = c_num * f_num with c_num = max(X(c_num)) over all training examples. Each example is zero-padded if necessary.

Thus, two examples of my training data looks like this:

```
dataX = [[0.281716105245517, 0.10665638086841528, 0.040441347270615546, 0.28939545406713674, 0.10708721346704864, 0.03575772540627547, 0.2919388156600431, 0.10567033629920064, 0.03548559505822619, 0.30111236802413277, 0.10374468925995455, 0.03198108511697361, 0.2712227031280739, 0.07861422245376401, 0.024556163928986227, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.29104112097787405, 0.10762980405837547, 0.03363727715955192, 0.31072658779074447, 0.11590693257359923, 0.03705562014318057, 0.3337477701497378, 0.14185185185185187, 0.05529482551143203, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
dataY = [2, 1]
```

Where dataY are the target lables, and denotes the second chunk as the answer for the first example; the first chunk, for the second example.

Having done so, I then ran the [OvR](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier) classier from the sklearn library as follows:

```py
# import libraries
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

# get data and train
dataX, dataY = getYour(awesome, training, data)
fit = OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(random_state=0)).fit(dataX, dataY)

# fit data and count number of correct
# classifications
correct = 0
prediction = fit.predict(yourNeatTestDataX)
for i in range(len(yourNeatTestDataY)):
    if dataY[i] == prediction[i]:
        correct += 1

print "Matches:", correct, "of", len(dataY),"=",float(correct)/len(dataY)
```